# Finding Year range in SQL (Microsoft Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

I recently discovered an old Microsoft Access database I made for recording a list of books and ticking off which ones I've read and in what year.

At the moment, this includes a BOOKS table which has a column for 'Read' and 'Year'. The query which generates the table of results gets the year column and counts how many books were read in each year, e.g:

- 2010: 8
- 2011: 10
- 2012: 20

**However**, this means that if no books are marked as read in, for example, 2015, then 2015 is just left out of the chart completely. Ideally it would show up with a value of 0.

Is there any way of doing this? I don't mind delving into the SQL itself. So far my initial thoughts are working out the number of years from 2010 to current year (using DateDiff), and somehow iterating over those years to count the number of books read... but I don't know if that's possible in SQL.

Comment: You can't group by a value that's not in the table, that's why 1845 is not in your result set... I suggest you manually manage the years you want in the DB; preferably, have a Years table with all years you want in the result set, and LEFT JOIN it to the books year by years.

Answer (score 3):

Create a numbers table with one row for each year in your target year range.  Then `LEFT JOIN` that table to `BOOKS` and do your counting ...

```sql
SELECT n.the_number, Nz(Count(b.Year), 0) AS books_read
FROM
    numbers AS n
    LEFT JOIN BOOKS AS b
    ON n.the_number = b.Year
WHERE n.the_number BETWEEN 2010 AND Year(Date())
GROUP BY n.the_number;
```

Note you would not need the `WHERE` clause if your numbers table contains only the years you're interested in.  However a numbers table can be useful in other situations where you might want a different range of numbers.  So a similar `WHERE` clause will allow you to target a specific subset of the numbers contained in the table.

Comment: I guess what I wanted was a more dynamic way, so on the 1st of Jan of the next year, that year would automatically be added to the table with a count of 0. But this is a good solution if that isn't possible! Thank you